# Connecting Marketing Cloud API User but says No Business Units available

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am in the middle of integrating Marketing Cloud with my Salesforce implementation.

On the Marketing Cloud Connector app I am trying to run "Connect to Marketing Cloud", however after a few seconds it says the following:

> The API user you are attempting to change to does not have access to
>   any Business Units. Please contact your Marketing Cloud administrator
>   to provide this user with at least one business unit in order to set
>   up as the API user.

The problem is, my Marketing Cloud instance only has ONE business unit, so the "Manage Business Unit" option in Admin > Users doesn't exist.

Is there something I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me, as if you are missing some of the steps in this guide: [Upgrade to Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_upgrade_to_connected_app_authentication.htm&type=5)
Usually, it is due to issues with the authentication between the two clouds.

One other issue could be the original mapping of your MC and CS integration users has go wrong. This can easily be resolved by [clearing out user mappings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214335&type=1) on connection user.

Comment: The user mappings instructions resolved this.